PHP ARTISAN TINKER is not responding and always shows an error
I am quite new to coding and trying to learn LARAVEL, now I am creating basic tables, factories, and models. As a terminal, I use Git Bash, for code editor VSCode, and for LARAVEL I use HERD on Windows. When I try to use "php artisan tinker" in the terminal I never get the starter message or any kind of starter indicator (>>> etc.), but that doesn't bother me that much.
The main issue is when I try to enter any tinker functions, such as find(), create(), all(), etc... the terminal always returns an error:
"PARSE ERROR  PHP Parse error: Unexpected character "SCII 27) in vendor\psy\psysh\src\Exception\ParseErrorException.php on line 44."
The mentioned file and line can be seen below:
(https://i.sstatic.net/BHyJbhLz.png)
I have not seen this problem mentioned by anyone on Git Hub or here, so I am clueless. I tried opening a new project with Herd, updating composer, rewriting things by hand, and some minor changes, but nothing changed. I also looked for hidden characters, which also didn't help.
After all this, I returned everything to its starting point, so any changes in code, etc.
Does anyone here know what the problem is? How could I fix this?

Sounds like there's a hidden ESC character somewhere. It could be on that file, it could be somewhere else. I have a linux command to try to find syntax errors in the whole project (find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep -v '^No syntax errors' on the command line), but I don't know what would work on Windows

@aynber I also suppose so, but I cannot find the syntax error. I tried to set Whitespaces in VSCode to all, but nothing changed, meaning I didn't find the said error/mistake. I also tried to rewrite the code by hand, also didn't work. Still thank you for the idea/contribution
